# Why I am getting Linker Error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, xcode6

My project contains the GoogleAnalytics library but still I am getting this error. I am also using cocoapoads as well. Please suggest the solution. I am using Xcode 6.1.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your `Library Search Paths` in build settings?

Comment: Yes What it should be? I have make it empty.

Comment: It should be the absolute path to where Google Analytics is